# how can I upgrade chocolatey?

Tags: node.js, windows, chocolatey

Basically I am facing problem with after install node … now I am try to upgrade chocolatey..

after run this command `choco upgrade chocolatey` below message I found.. ***Windows 10***

> Chocolatey v0.10.15
> Upgrading the following packages:
> chocolatey
> By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
> Error retrieving packages from source 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/':
> The operation has timed out

> chocolatey was not found with the source(s) listed.
> If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message,

> **it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
> Version: ""; Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"**

> Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
> See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

> Warnings:
> chocolatey - chocolatey was not found with the source(s) listed.

***Does anyone have any idea about this ?***

Comment: choco upgrade chocolatey

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the install command, this should just replace and update chocolatey:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Also please make sure you have set PowerShell to accept the security protocol to: `$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy`

This has to be done before the choco install command.

Also, another way just to update node without updating Chocolatey is to just run the following command: `choco install nodejs-lts --version=14.17.3 --confirm --timeout 216000;`

Comment: This unfortunately does not help as `WARNING: 'choco' was found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe'.
WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue.
For security reasons, this script will not overwrite existing installations`